# May I use UbuntuOne to share files from my business?

Tags: ubuntu-one

Me (and my partners) have developed a point & click adventure game. It is a game that runs on windows (and hopefully Linux.. it is still being tested) and the installer is about 330M.

The game is Free, and thus, have no budget. But anyway we want to be able to distribute it through the new Windows 8 Store.

So, we were thinking about uploading the game to Ubuntu One and link from everywhere directly to this file for free download.

May I use UbuntuOne this way or is it only for personal use? Is there a limit about the downloads or bandwidth used for download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a perfect answer you should ask it on the [U1 support page](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/). But the [terms of services](https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/#your-account) seem not to exclude what you want.

> Acceptable use and conduct
>
> All usage of the services must be legal and not infringe any third party's rights. You must not take any action or use the services in any way that might bring Canonical into disrepute, affect the ability of Canonical to provide the services, be illegal, or encourage illegal activities. You may not use the services in any manner that might be libellous or defamatory (more info on what that means), that contains threats or incites violence towards individuals or entities, or that violates the privacy or publicity rights of any third party. Some services have usage limitations as indicated at https://one.ubuntu.com/plans, and you may not exceed these. As part of the services, you may store data on Canonical's servers or those of Canonical's suppliers. You should ensure that this data is not in breach of any applicable law and does not breach any individual's data protection or privacy rights. You shall indemnify Canonical in full for any loss, cost or damages suffered by it as a result of your use or misuse of the services.

---

Technically if the amount of downloads get out of hand you could be `affecting the ability of Canonical to provide the services`.

Comment: Thanks ! Specially for the support page that I failed to find.

Answer (score 1):

I see nothing in the [terms](https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/) that would prohibit that.

Further, the examples even include reference to "business" use, by saying:

> Sharing files with Ubuntu One is easy and secure. Any photo you take
>   appears on all your devices, the instant you take it so you can share
>   with family, friends, **colleagues** or push to your social networks.

(emph mine), although you could say that colleagues are just people you know. Nevertheless, taking the terms into account, I don't see any problem.

There is on the other hand, no guarantee of bandwith, amount of threads to the file, etc.